# Alternative to Preview app to search for text in multiple documents at the same time

Tags: pdf, preview, search

I need to search for texts in several `PDF` at the same time. `Preview` does the job: I select the files in the Finder and open them together in `Preview`. Then, searching for some text happens simultaneously in all the `PDF`: great! But is very unstable. When searching, it often crashes.

Is there an alternative to `Preview` with the same feature?

My system is 10.11.6 and Preview is 8.1

Comment: Evernote Premium and DevonTHINK apps can search in PDF files, but they all are not free.

Comment: Yes good idea @pjctech

Answer (score 1):

**Use Spotlight.**

> Spotlight is a system-wide desktop search feature of Apple's macOS and
>   iOS operating systems. Spotlight is a selection-based search system,
>   which creates an index of all items and files on the system. It is
>   designed to allow the user to quickly locate a wide variety of items
>   on the computer, including documents, pictures, music, applications,
>   and System Preferences. In addition, specific words in documents and
>   in web pages in a web browser's history or bookmarks can be searched.
>   It also allows the user to narrow down searches with creation dates,
>   modification dates, sizes, types and other attributes.

With Spotlight you can do advanced searches and filter for example on file extensions like `.pdf`.

[image: Finder Spotlight]